# Давайте организуем следующий выпуск видеочата сообщества, посвящённый удалённой работе!

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

Формат «базы знаний» не всегда позволяет нам раскрыть все свои интересы, свою личность. Чтобы компенсировать это и познакомиться поближе мы проводим [видеочат](/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82) сообщества.

Для организации следующего выпуска видеочата, мне очень нужна ваша помощь: я бы хотел найти среди участников двоих людей, которые работают удалённо.  На мой взгляд, нашим коллегам было бы очень интересно, если бы мы поговорили о своём жизненном опыте удалённой работы:

- Как нашли свою компанию?
- Как обустроили свои рабочие процессы?
- Как социализируются?

И многое другое.

Если вы хотите поделиться с коллегами своим опытом удалённой работы, пожалуйста, напишите мне на почту об этом: nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com Я свяжусь с вами, и мы обговорим удобное для вас время и интересующие вас темы беседы.

Давайте рассказывать о себе, своих интересах и делиться своим жизненным опытом в видеоформате!

Comment: @defaultlocale *работе удалённо

Comment: @defaultlocale по правилами русского языка там должно быть `Давайте организуем следующий выпуск видеочата сообщества, посвящённый удалённой работе`.

Comment: @defaultlocale Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь внести правку, которая улучшит содержание сообщения.

Comment: Я работаю удалённо:-)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Здорово! Я отпишусь вам в ближайшее время! =)

Comment: Как мне казалось, на Хабре эта тема уже полностью освещена: и про плюсы писали, и про минусы, и про мифы.

Comment: @AntonSorokin тут типо из первых уст при живом общении.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ну что, есть какой-нибудь прогресс?

Comment: @AntonSorokin Ищем второго участника!

Comment: Я не работаю удалённо, но возможно для следующей темы я бы смог выступить. А тему можно взять такую: разработка OpenSource проектов. Тема может быть интересна с аспектов выбора технологий, заработка, раскрутки и рекламы, временных затрат, привлечения участников, и с других позиций. Прошу прощение за офтоп, можно перенести в личный чат.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Наинтереснейшая тема! Спасибо! Подскажите, пожалуйста, не хотите ли создать подобный этому вопрос для поиска второго участника видеочата (два участника, на мой взгляд — оптимально)?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Написать главную тему не смогу, думаю у вас как у главы нашего русскоязычного сообщества, это получится значительно лучше чем у меня. Но, конечно, приму участие в обсуждении и подготовке. И честно говоря сейчас совсем нет времени,  почти всё время всецело уходит на мой проект. Если кто-то начнёт, я присоединюсь к обсуждению, но написать главный пост мне не в тему будет.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Отлично! Тогда я напишу вопрос =)