# Выпуск видеочата №7 с @Vadim Ovchinnikov 24.07.2019 в 10:12. Присоединяйтесь!

Tags: обсуждение, видеочат

С радостью спешу пригласить всех участников сообщества присоединиться к видеочату в среду, 24 июля 2019 года в 10:12 по московскому времени. Гостем седьмого выпуска будет [@Vadim Ovchinnikov](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/220571/vadim-ovchinnikov?tab=profile). Вадим в свое время поступил в харьковский политех на химика–технолога, впоследствии сменив фокус на программирование. На данный момент является старшим .NET разработчиком. Любимые языки Вадима: C#, HTML/CSS, JavaScript, TypeScript, SQL.

Тема этого выпуска — [удалённая работа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9129/6). Видео будет доступно в реальном времени на канале сообщества: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BZNpv7BXQQ.

#### Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы!

Главная цель видеочата – узнать друг друга поближе. Расскажите, что бы вам хотелось узнать о удаленной работе или опыте участника выпуска! Пожалуйста, задавайте ваши вопросы Вадиму!

Ваши вопросы вы можете задать в [чате сообщества](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--) ( обязательно, задавая вопрос, упомяните `@NicolasChabanovsky`, чтобы я мог своевременно отреагировать на вопрос). Также вы можете отправить ваш вопрос заранее мне на почту (nicolas.chabanovsky@stackoverflow.com) или опубликовать комментарием или ответом на данный вопрос.

С нетерпением ждем вас 24-го июля в 10:12!

Answer (score 7):

Ответы на вопросы из чата Youtube (простите, впервые у меня видеочат, не отследил вопросы, думал Николас зачитает, если будут):

**Вопрос:** Как не выгореть на фрилансе? Получается ли держать режим дня?
**Ответ:** Я не фрилансер, работаю на компанию, просто удалённо. Могу разве что ответить на вопрос как не выгореть. Чтобы не выгорать, нужно соблюдать баланс работы и отдыха и не принуждать себя работать, когда не хочется. Режим дня держать получается, но это скорее связано с самодисциплиной.

**Вопрос:** а так сума не сойдешь если 24 часа в сутки работа и работа?
**Ответ:** Я не работаю 24 часа в сутки, в среднем 8 часов.

**Вопрос:** Вопрос, сколько уделяешь времени на прокачку новых навыков, чтение книг, и т.д.?
**Ответ:** Сложно ответить точно, но хотя бы часов 20 в месяц получается.

**Вопрос:** Также интересно, насколько часто выделяешь время на посещение различных мероприятий по интересующим технологиям в твоем городе.
**Ответ:** Ну они бывает не так и часто, поэтому чаще чем 1-2 раза в год не посещаю. Иногда не успеваю, поэтому смотрю в записе.

Comment: 20 часов в месяц - это час в день. Маловато )=

Comment: @Suvitruf Не все программисты даже столько уделяют времени профессиональному развитию, иногда эта цифра больше. Главное — стабильно.